Node - MySQL2 not dropping idle connections using pools
We are starting to push out our web app out to users for testing and we are running into any issue with the MySQL connections.  After a while the database calls just stop working and I go out to our hosting provider and see that there is a whole bunch of open connections sitting out there.  I close them all and then things start working again.  So there must be an issue with my code.  I am using Node with the 'mysql2/promise' package and a MySQL managed database on Digital Ocean.  I am using pools.  But I must be doing something wrong in my code.
This is what the stuck connections look like on DO:

And here are the three main functions on my Node server where the issue might reside:
const executeMultipleQueries = async (
    queries: { query: string; vars: (string | number | boolean | null)[] }[]
) => {
    if (queries.length) {
        let connection;
        let results: string | any[] = [];
        try {
            connection = await pool.getConnection();
            await connection.beginTransaction();
            for (const query of queries) {
                let result;
                if (query.vars.length) {
                    result = await connection.query<ResultSetHeader[]>(
                        query.query,
                        query.vars
                    );
                } else {
                    result = await connection.query<ResultSetHeader[]>(
                        query.query
                    );
                }
                if (result.length) {
                    results.push(result[0][0]);
                }
            }
            await connection.commit();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log({e});
            await connection?.rollback();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            console.log('releasing...');
            connection?.release();
        }

        return results;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
const executeQuery = async (
    query: string,
    multipleResults: boolean,
    params: (string | null)[] | []
) => {
    // const conn = await pool.getConnection();

    let rows: any[], fields, err;
    try {
        if (!params.length) {
            [rows, fields] = await pool.query(query);
        } else {
            [rows, fields] = await pool.query(query, params); //await pool.query(query, params);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
    // pool.release();

    // if (!err) {
    if (!multipleResults) {
        return rows[0];
    } else {
        return rows;
    }
    // } else {
    //  return err;
    // }
};

const executeSP = async (
    query: string,
    multipleResults = false,
    params: any[] | [] = []
) => {
    if (!query.startsWith('CALL')) {
        query = 'CALL ' + query;
    }
    if (!query.endsWith(')') && params.length) {
        // we need to add the question marks for the params, i.e. (?,?,?)
        query += '(';
        const questions = new Array(params.length).fill('?').join(',');
        query += questions + ')';
    }
    query += ';';

    console.log({query, multipleResults, params});

    try {
        return await executeQuery(query, multipleResults, params);
    } catch (e: any) {
        console.log({e});
        // @ts-ignore
        if (e?.code === 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
            const sqlMessage = e?.sqlMessage;
            const tableWithFieldName = sqlMessage
                .split(' for key ')[1]
                .replaceAll("'", '');
            const fieldName = tableWithFieldName.split('.')[1];
            return {
                error: {
                    msg: 'Duplicate Entry for field: ' + capitalize(fieldName)
                }
            };
        }
        return {error: e};
    }
};

And here is how I initially create the pool:
const pool = mysql2.createPool({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.MYSQL_PORT),
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_QUOTES_DB,
    debug: false,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    waitForConnections: true,
    maxIdle: 10, // max idle connections, the default value is the same as `connectionLimit`
    idleTimeout: 60000, // idle connections timeout, in milliseconds, the default value 60000
    queueLimit: 0,
    enableKeepAlive: true,
    keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
    ssl: {
        ca: fs.readFileSync(xxxxx || '') // I x'd out the path
    },
    typeCast: function castField(field, useDefaultTypeCasting) {
        // We only want to cast bit fields that have a single-bit in them. If the field
        // has more than one bit, then we cannot assume it is supposed to be a Boolean.
        if (field.type === 'BIT' && field.length === 1) {
            const bytes = field.buffer();
            // A Buffer in Node represents a collection of 8-bit unsigned integers.
            // Therefore, our single "bit field" comes back as the bits '0000 0001',
            // which is equivalent to the number 1.
            return bytes ? bytes[0] === 1 : false;
        }
        return useDefaultTypeCasting();
    }
});

export default pool;

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  I thought I would need to release or close the pool somewhere.  Also it appears my pool gets created once when my node server starts and then just reused from there on.  Is that correct?
Follow up question, I can't find many details on the 'connectionLimit'.  Would I have a lot of issues if I set that to something like 100 instead of 10?

Can yous see "Releasing..." entries in the node.js log?

Yes, I tried several different insert queries and that logs out once per query.

And can you see the corresponding connection terminated in mysql?

How/where do I check that?

checkout the acquire/enqueue/release events
you can add  - https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql?tab=readme-ov-file#connection-options, they may be of assistance to track

what if you set the idleTimeout to 2minutes rather than 10 ? , check if any entries are in a sleep state ... , set maxIdle to 1 rather than 10 ..  lots to try/tweak ...

Thank you.  These seem like pretty sensible defaults to me.  Just glancing at them without knowing all the intricacies, I would think they would safely and easily support 10 different users concurrently.  But as it stands its not even supporting 2 concurrent users.  I will play around with the values.
